# Redux mutation detected between dispatches

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm having some trouble with a react redux I'm currently working on. I'm relatively new to Redux so maybe I'm missing a simple concept here but what I'm trying to do is build a deck building app for a card game and I want to be able to save the deck anytime a user adds or removes a card from their deck.

However, anytime I click add or remove I'm receiving the following error message while trying to dispatch an update action.

The error message reads as follows:

```
Uncaught Error: A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path `decks.0.cards.mainboard.0.quantity`. This may cause incorrect behavior.
```

My container component

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import DeckMobileDisplay from './DeckMobileDisplay';
import * as deckActions from '../../actions/deckActions';

export class DeckEditorContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            deck: Object.assign({}, this.props.deck)
        }

        this.addCard = this.addCard.bind(this);
        this.removeCard = this.removeCard.bind(this);
    }

    addCard(board, cardName) {
        let deck = this.state.deck;
        let cards = this.state.deck.cards;

        cards[board].forEach(i => {
             if(i.name === cardName)
                i.quantity += 1;
        });

        const update = Object.assign(deck, cards);

        this.props.deckActions.updateDeck(update).then(deck => {
            console.log(deck);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    removeCard(board, cardName) {
        let deck = this.state.deck;
        let cards = this.state.deck.cards;

        cards[board].forEach(i => {
             if(i.name === cardName) {
                 if (i.quantity === 1) {
                     cards[board].splice(cards[board].indexOf(i), 1);
                 }
                 else {
                     i.quantity -= 1;
                 }

             }
        });

        const update = Object.assign(deck, cards);

        this.props.deckActions.updateDeck(update).then(deck => {
            console.log(deck);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    render() {
        const deck = Object.assign({}, this.props.deck);

        return (
            <div className="editor-container">
                <DeckMobileDisplay
                    deck={deck}
                    addCard={this.addCard}
                    removeCard={this.removeCard}
                    />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

DeckEditorContainer.PropTypes = {
    deck: PropTypes.object
};

function getDeckById(decks, id) {
    const deck = decks.filter(deck => deck.id == id);

    if (deck.length) return deck[0];
    return null;
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    const deckId = ownProps.params.id;
    let deck = {
        id: '',
        userId: '',
        cards: []
    }

    if (state.decks.length > 0) {
        deck = getDeckById(state.decks, deckId);
    }

    return {
        deck: deck
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        deckActions: bindActionCreators(deckActions, dispatch)
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DeckEditorContainer);
```

Component for DeckMobileDisplay

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import TabContainer from '../common/Tabs/TabContainer';
import Tab from '../common/Tabs/Tab';
import CardSearchContainer from '../CardSearch/CardSearchContainer';
import DeckList from './DeckList.js';

class DeckMobileDisplay extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <TabContainer>
                <Tab title="DeckList">
                    <DeckList
                        deck={this.props.deck}
                        addCard={this.props.addCard}
                        removeCard={this.props.removeCard}
                    />
                </Tab>
                <Tab title="Search">
                    <CardSearchContainer
                        addCard={this.props.addCard}
                        removeCard={this.props.removeCard}
                        />
                </Tab>
                <Tab title="Stats">
                    <p>stats coming soon...</p>
                </Tab>
            </TabContainer>
        );
    }
}

DeckMobileDisplay.propTypes = {
    deck: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    addCard: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    removeCard: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default DeckMobileDisplay;
```

Related Actions

```
export function createDeck(deck) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(beginAjaxCall());

        const config = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' },
            body : JSON.stringify({deck: deck})
        };

        return fetch(`http://localhost:3000/users/${deck.userId}/decks`, config)
            .then(res => res.json().then(deck => ({deck, res})))
            .then(({res, deck}) => {
                if (res.status >= 200 && res.status < 300) {
                    dispatch(createDeckSuccess(deck.deck));
                }
                else
                    dispatch(createDeckFailure(deck));
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                dispatch(ajaxCallError(err));
            });
    };
}

export function updateDeck(deck) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(beginAjaxCall());

        const body = JSON.stringify({deck: deck});

        const config = {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers : { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' },
            body: body
        };

        return fetch(`http://localhost:3000/decks/${deck.id}`, config)
            .then(res => res.json().then(deck => ({deck, res})))
            .then(({res, deck}) => {
                if (res.status >= 200 && res.status < 300) {
                    dispatch(updateDeckSuccess(deck.deck));
                }
                    dispatch(ajaxCallError(err));
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                dispatch(ajaxCallError(err));
            });
    };
}

export function updateDeckSuccess(deck) {
    return {
        type: types.UPDATE_DECK_SUCCESS,
        deck
    };
}
```

And my deck Reducer

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';
import initialState from './initialState';

export default function deckReducer(state = initialState.decks, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.LOAD_USERS_DECKS_SUCCESS:
            return action.decks;

        case types.CREATE_DECK_SUCCESS:
            return [
                ...state,
                Object.assign({}, action.deck)
            ]

        case types.UPDATE_DECK_SUCCESS:
            return [
                ...state.filter(deck => deck.id !== action.deck.id),
                Object.assign({}, action.deck)
            ]

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

If you need to see more of the app the repo is here:

https://github.com/dgravelle/magic-redux

Any kind of help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Your problem might be caused because you are modifying this.state.deck.cards in removeCards. You should clone the array instead. I only saw the code, I cant test it right now. Try to use Object.assign to clone your array or store the quantity into a variable.

Comment: I mean, you are.modifying quantity when you do i.quantity += 1;. You are modifying the state manually there.

Comment: Good catch, I had been overlooking i.quantity += 1. Using Obect.assign works. Thanks!

Comment: I will add my comment as answer so it will help to others. Please, could you accept it and vote it up? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is caused because you are modifying component's state manually.
One Redux's principle is:

> ### State is read-only
>
> The only way to change the state is to emit an action, an object
>   describing what happened.
>
> This ensures that neither the views nor the network callbacks will
>   ever write directly to the state. Instead, they express an intent to
>   transform the state. Because all changes are centralized and happen
>   one by one in a strict order, there are no subtle race conditions to
>   watch out for. As actions are just plain objects, they can be logged,
>   serialized, stored, and later replayed for debugging or testing
>   purposes.

In the method `removeCard` you are modifying the state:

```js
removeCard(board, cardName) {
    let deck = this.state.deck;
    //This is just a reference, not a clone
    let cards = this.state.deck.cards;

    cards[board].forEach(i => {
         if(i.name === cardName) {
             if (i.quantity === 1) {
                 //Here you are modifying cards, which is a pointer to this.state.deck.cards
                 cards[board].splice(cards[board].indexOf(i), 1);
             }
             else {
                 //Here you are modifying cards, which is a pointer to this.state.deck.cards
                 i.quantity -= 1;
             }
         }
    });
    //... more stuff
}
```

One concept you might be missing is that `this.state.deck.cards` is a reference/pointer to the Array's memory position. You need to clone it if you want to mutate it.

One solution could be to clone the original array instead:

```js
removeCard(board, cardName) {
    let deck = this.state.deck;
    //Here you are cloning the original array, so cards references to a totally different memory position
    let cards = Object.assign({}, this.state.deck.cards);

    cards[board].forEach(i => {
         if(i.name === cardName) {
             if (i.quantity === 1) {
                 cards[board].splice(cards[board].indexOf(i), 1);
             }
             else {
                 i.quantity -= 1;
             }

         }
    });
    //... more stuff
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: So I no longer receive the error that "A state mutation was detected between dispatches" however, now my connected container is not re-rendering with the updated redux state. I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong with this issue now...

Comment: Because now the state is no longer being modified. You should move all the logic for adding/removing cards to your reducer. In the component you only should have the action dispatching.